# AWS fargate cluster - limitations and best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a fargate cluster in dev environment which contains an ecs service supporting a single client.

We need to on-board 50 more clients. So wanted to know what are some best practices around fargate clusters. I looked around and did not find any suitable content(including aws fargate FAQ). Can anyone help me with the below:

1. Should I create one fargate cluster per client or within same fargate cluster create one ecs service per client ? Which one is better and why ?
2. Is there any limitation on how many fargate clusters can be created in aws ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-quotas.html 10,000 clusters, adjustable. The first question heavily depends on the specific requirements relating to security / isolation between the clients / customers and how you want to mange them.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say it depends but none of the options you can pick will result in you doing anything wrong. A cluster in Fargate doesn't have a very specific meaning because there are no container instances you would provision and attach to said cluster(s) to provide capacity. In the context of Fargate a cluster really just become some sort of "folder" or namespace. The only real advantage of having multiple clusters is because you can scope your users at the cluster level and delegate the ability to deploy in said clusters. If you don't have a specific need like that, for simplicity you are probably good with just one cluster and 50 separate ECS services in it.